# How to make an electrical connection to thin gold plating?

Tags: pcb, soldering, pcb-assembly, pad, gold

Hello fellow engineers.

I am trying to make an electrical connection with some gold plating.  The gold plating is shaped like a rectangle, with dimensions of 3mm x 1.5mm x 0.1μm thick.  [Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QL2L2C5) is what the part looks like, it's quite small.

My procedure is:

1. Tin some 24 gauge stranded copper wire
2. Apply flux to the gold pad
3. Attempt to solder the wire to the pad

Every time I try to solder (using standard solder: 63% tin, 37% lead solder wire, flux core, 0.6mm diameter.  [the solder I used](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00R1PTRE2)), I end up with a failed connection within one second of solder flow.  What I mean by this is, all the gold seems to disappear, and I am left with an extra-tinned wire.  I think what happens is the gold is absorbed into the solder, as Wikipedia states [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_plating#Soldering_issues).

I am wondering, how do you suggest I make a reliable electrical connection to this part?

**Edit 1**

Per comments:
 - Tip: Metcal [STTC-144](http://www.okinternational.com/metcal/english/globalnavigation/products/hand-soldering-systems/tips-and-cartridges/mx-cartridges/sttc-series-conical), with a [MX-PS5200 PSU](http://www.okinternational.com/hand-soldering-systems/id-MX-PS5200/Power_supply_for_MX-5200_Series).  I am not sure what temperature the tip is at during soldering.
 - Substrate: from the [product description](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QL2L2C5) that the substrate is Si, with 0.3μm of SiO2, then 0.01μm of Cr, then 0.1μm of Au.

Comment: You're burning it away? What is the substrate? And what tip, iron, and temperature? are you using? Photos of the damage too.

Comment: It says "bonding and soldering are easy"  :P.  If we can't help you get it soldered, you could always try conductive epoxy.

Comment: @DKNguyen I added all the information you requested.

Comment: @TimWescott, thank you that is also a good backup plan!

Comment: That tip isn't doing you any favours. It's both small and round for poor contact rather than large and flat. But 0.01um of Cr is real thin. I thought there would be something more under the Au but I guess not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gold dissolves in tin.  There is an indium solder called "TIX".  It requires a strong flux, "TIX flux".  You can get it on Amazon.
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Robert Endl, I just bought a TIX kit, ASIN [B017L4EHCY](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B017L4EHCY/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A1DPYO2JO3I12K&psc=1).  Will circle back on how it performs!

Comment: This worked!! I think their antiflux is quite useful :) My method consisted of 1. thin wire (tinned with TIX solder), ~26 AWG stranded.  2. I placed the chip with the 0.1μm thick pads on the table.  3. I placed a thin strip of metal over the interdigitated electrodes, to protect them from solder spatter (I found antiflux too hard to work with in this case, lol). 4. I placed the tinned wire on the pad.  5. I applied flux to both the tinned wire and the pad.  6. I put a bit more solder on my iron (flat tip), and pressed it down, completing the solder!

Comment: Thank you again @RobertEndl!

Comment: Be sure to clean the flux off.  I think the stuff is corrosive.